# SVN conflict with no file on hard drive

Tags: linux, svn

I have two PCs and svn repo. I've added file to svn using my notebook and said svn up on the other. The file is new, it doesn't exist on my 2nd PC but I get:

```
@konrad:~/svn$ ls web/web/browser.xslt.xml
ls: cannot access web/web/browser.xslt.xml: No such file or directory

@konrad~/svn$ svn up
Conflict discovered in 'web/web/WEB-INF/xslt/browser.xslt.xml'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
        (s) show all options:
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Maybe it's both-deleted conflict? What does (df) show?

Comment: Is it a typo that you `ls web/web/browser.xslt.xml` but the conflict arises in `web/web/WEB-INF/xslt/browser.xslt.xml`? The conflicting path has `WEB-INF` in it, the `ls`-path doesn't...

Comment: You are right, eckes, but still I am not sure if file was there. I'll update the question if I face this again.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ls` shows a different file: `web/web/browser.xslt.xml` and not `web/web/WEB-INF/xslt/browser.xslt.xml`. Are you sure you don't have `web/web/WEB-INF/xslt/browser.xslt.xml` on your system?

I run into these mysterious conflicts all the time and it is frustrating because you can't do anything until you get this resolved. I guess you could do a *diff-full* and then decide on what to merge or how to merge, but I've always find that frustrating because I can't really take the time to think and resolve the issue.

Kill the update and do a `svn status`. This will give you the reason. Maybe you've deleted the file with `svn delete` and there's an incoming update to this file. Maybe you added the file and someone else did too. Maybe you have a non-subversion version of the file on your drive, and someone added it in Subversion. Sometimes, I find the conflict is nothing more than a conflict in the `svn:mergeinfo` property.

The easiest thing to do is just get rid of the problem and accept whatever is now in the repository:

1. Do an `svn resolved` on the file. That will get it out of the *conflicted state*.
2. Now do a `svn status` on the file. This will show you what Subversion thinks you did. For example, did you delete this file or add this file.
3. If you see the file was *modified*, do a diff on it, so you can see what was modified. Remember that the diff can be a property value too!
4. For safety sake if the file exists in your working copy, copy the file elsewhere.
5. Do a `svn revert` on it. A `svn status` should show the file is pristine.
6. Now, you can do a `svn update` on the file. You will now have the latest copy from the repository.

Once you have everything cleared up, you can decide how to proceed. Even if this was a true conflict between changes I made and changes someone was making, I still prefer to do it this way. I can use `vimdiff` to see what the differences are and what to update much easier than doing it in the middle of an update.